# except ValueError in Python

Tags: python

Is there better way of writing this code:

```
def add (exe1, exe2):
    try:
        a = float (exe1)
        b = float (exe2)
        total = float (a + b)
    except ValueError:
        return None
    else:
        return total
```

Answer (score 1):

You can have it all inside a `try/except` block (calculation and `return`):

```
def add(exe1, exe2):
    try:
        return float(exe1) + float(exe2)
    except ValueError:
        return None
```

Also note, the default return value from function is `None`, so the second `return` is not really necessary (you could have `pass` instead), but it makes code more readable.

Answer (score 0):

You can also use contextlib.suppress, if you find it more readable.

```
from contextlib import suppress
def add(exe1, exe2):
    with suppress(ValueError):
        return float(exe1) + float(exe2)
```

See the documentation [here](https://docs.python.org/3/library/contextlib.html#contextlib.suppress).